# Sum of groupby timestamp with grafana/elasticsearch : value always 0

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have data that looks like:

```
datetime    resolution_code area_code   area_type_code  area_name   map_code    total_load_value    update_time
"2014-12-31 23:15:00"   "PT15M" "10Y1001A1001A83F"  "CTY"   "DE CTY"    "DE"    44474.91
"2014-12-31 23:00:00"   "PT15M" "10Y1001A1001A83F"  "CTY"   "DE CTY"    "DE"    44839.67
"2014-12-31 23:45:00"   "PT15M" "10Y1001A1001A83F"  "CTY"   "DE CTY"    "DE"    44507.17
"2014-12-23 07:00:00"   "PT60M" "10YES-REE------0"  "CTY"   "ES CTY"    "ES"    31164
```

I primarly stored these data on PostgreSQL and then through logstash I push the data into Elasticsearch.

```
input {
  jdbc {
     jdbc_driver_library => "path/postgresql-42.6.0.jar"
     jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/european_energy_data"
     jdbc_user => "user"
     jdbc_password => "password"
     jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
     statement => "SELECT * from public.total_load LIMIT 10000"
 }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        convert => { "date_time" => "string" }
        convert => { "total_load_value" => "float"}
    }
      date {
        match => ["date_time", "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'Z'"]
        target => "@datetime"
      }
    }

output {
    stdout {}
    elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
    index => "network"
    }
}
```

I got the data on elastic search.
I would like the total_load_value by hour or day.

With CURL query, everything is fine:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/network/_search?&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "_index:'network'"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "load_by_year": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "date_time",
            "calendar_interval": "day"
        },
    "aggs" : {
    "total_load_value": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "total_load_value"
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
'
```

However, impossible to get this one through grafana. If I tried to aggregate by summing my values, everything is put to 0.

EDIT : as @jan-garaj noted, my screenshots of grafana were wrong as I grouped by with `@timestamp` and not `date_time`. So I removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed with small changes in the pipeline.conf.
The main change was to remove `LIMIT` to upload all my table. It was a stupid mistake of mine. I was quite exhausted apparently.
Also, through several tests, I noted I lost some data during the SQL injection when the page size was too important and I missed the `ORDER BY` SQL command.

I did not explore much more why. I'll edit when I'll get time.

```
input {
  jdbc {
     jdbc_driver_library => "path/postgresql-42.6.0.jar"
     jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/european_energy_data"
     jdbc_user => "user"
     jdbc_password => "password"
     jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
     jdbc_paging_enabled => true # to avoid memory crash
     jdbc_page_size => 100000 # size of the page not too big
     statement => "SELECT * from public.total_load ORDER BY date_time ASC" # seems important to add ORDER BY to get complete injection.
 }
}

# filter not needed anymore, date_time was already recognized as ISO timestamp. 

output {
    # stdout {}
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "network"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong time field in Grafana `@timestamp`. It looks like you should use `@datetime` (maybe `day_time`).

Try to configure time field for you index in the Grafana datasource configuration properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, I resolve the problem. The problem was the SQL query which was too short. When I did it again but with a `ORDER BY` with `ASC` option, It worked.

But you were right about the `@timestamp` was a mistake of mine. I made a wrong screenshot.

I'm going to edit.